# Android HTML data parsing specific line

Tags: java, android, html, parsing

```
<br /><br /><b>REGISTER NO &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 1515041 </b><br><br><b>NAME &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SELVAMANI K<br><br>BRANCH&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;B.E.Computer Science and Engineering</b><br><br><table class="ui blue unstackable very compact striped table"><thead><tr><th>SUBCODE</th><th>SUBNAME</th><th>SEMNO</th><th>GRADE</th><th>RESULT</th></b></th></thead><tbody><tr align='left'><td>15MAB12</td><td>Discrete Mathematics</td><td>4</td><td>B+</td><td>P</b></td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr align='left'><td>15CSC04</td><td>Data Structure - II</td><td>3</td><td>F</td><td>F</b></td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr align='left'><td>15CSC05</td><td>Design and Analysis of Algorithms</td><td>4</td><td>B</td><td>P</b></td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr align='left'><td>15CSC06</td><td>Operating Systems</td><td>4</td><td>B</td><td>P</b></td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr align='left'><td>15CSC07</td><td>Database Management Systems</td><td>4</td><td>C</td><td>P</b></td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr align='left'><td>15CSC74</td><td>Operating Systems Lab</td><td>4</td><td>A</td><td>P</b></td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr align='left'><td>15CSC75</td><td>Database Management Systems Lab</td><td>4</td><td>A</td><td>P</b></td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr align='left'><td>15CSE01</td><td>Total Quality Management</td><td>4</td><td>B+</td><td>P</b></td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr align='left'><td>15CSS06</td><td>Microprocessors and Microcontrollers</td><td>4</td><td>B+</td><td>P</b></td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr align='left'><td>15CSS75</td><td>Microprocessors and Microcontroller Lab</td><td>4</td><td>A+</td><td>P</b></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

This line in html document in 35th line and i want to extract only the data between the tags what i should do?

explain please!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you parse HTML in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114282/how-can-you-parse-html-in-android)

Comment: Give up and write a proper web service.  There's no good reason to parse html.

Comment: Can you provide your JSON ?

Answer (score 0):

> First you need to convert that Html string into plaintext , then you are able to parse that 35th line from your JSON..

- When parser goes to 35th line you should get that string into **String Variable** .After that you may try this

  String plainText = Html.fromHtml(Html.fromHtml(mHtmlString).toString())