# How to make a pattern-matcher regex for html tags?

Tags: android, html, regex

I am trying to match pattern for getting tag and data between two html tag.

to replace data between two tags i want to inspect elements for that Pattern 
i want to make pattern regex so i can match it with html elements and reach to that point and replace data between  tags.

if anybody know how to create regex pattern for below html tags.

My HTML file is like this:

```
 <div id="frame">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="messages">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="sent">
                            <img src="http://emilcarlsson.se/assets/mikeross.png" alt="" />
                            <p>####data</p>
                        </li>
                        <li class="replies">
                            <img src="http://emilcarlsson.se/assets/harveyspecter.png" alt="" />
                            <p>####data</p>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

what i done:

```
 public void readWritedatatFromHtml(){
        InputStream input;
        try {

            input = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.view);

            int size = input.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            input.read(buffer);
            input.close();

            String text = new String(buffer);

            //  Pattern tags = Pattern.compile ("<div class=\"content\">+<div class=\"messages\">+<ul>");
           // Pattern tags = Pattern.compile ("<div class=\"content\">\n<div class=\"messages\">");
           // Pattern tags = Pattern.compile ("<div class=\"content\">(.*?)<ul>");


            Pattern tags = Pattern.compile ("<div class=\"messages\">.? </div>");
            Matcher m = tags.matcher(text);
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            while (m.find()) {
                m.appendReplacement(sb, " <ul> <li class=\"sent1\">\n" +
                        "                            <img src=\"http://emilcarlsson.se/assets/mikeross.png\" alt=\"\" />\n" +
                        "                            <p>####data</p>\n" +
                        "                        </li>");
            }

            m.appendTail(sb);
            Log.i("sb",sb.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, after try some pattern i find something like this which is perfectly working for me:

```
 Pattern tags = Pattern.compile ("<div\\s+class=\"messages\">[\\S\\s]*?<\\/div>");
```

as @JGNI suggested we should avoid this but right now it's right for my requirement if anybody has any better option please guide me so it can helpful to others as well.

Answer (score 1):

Do not under any circumstances try to parse HTML with a regex unless you wish to invoke [rite <sub>6</sub>6<sup>6</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) *Ph'nglui mglw'nafh Cthulhu R'lyeh wgah'nagl fhtagn.*

Use an HTML parsing library see [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114282/how-can-you-parse-html-in-android) for some ways to do it.

Comment: i think you are right but i think but my requirement is like that may be that's why i have to do it but you should avoid this for best practice.