# Regular Expression to match parent and sub node

Tags: regex

I want to development a regular expresion to match the tag :

```
<claim-text>aaaaaaa
    <claim-text>bbbbbbb</claim-text>
    <claim-text>ccccccc</claim-text>
</claim-text>
```

I tried

```
<claim-text>(.*)</claim-text>
```

But, only bbbbbbb and ccccccc can be matched. Can I get some help to cover aaaaaaa also?

Thanks

Comment: Activate the s/single line/'. matches \n' flag.

Comment: `s.split(/\s*<\/?claim-text>\s*/).filter(Boolean)`

Comment: What should the result be if your tag structure looked like `<claim-text>aaaaaaa<claim-text>bbbbbbb</claim-text><claim-text>ccccccc</claim-text>ddddddd</claim-text>`?

Answer (score 1):

For a generic solution with any depth, you will at least need a stack, which not available for most regular expression implementation. However, if you know the structure will only have the depth you specified, you could use something like this:

```
<claim-text>([^<\r\n]*)
```

You can see a working example here: https://regex101.com/r/kbDbwF/1

It will search for your opening tag, and then find anything up to the next opening or closing tag `[^<]`, or to the next line break `[^\r\n]`. I have combined both character classes to one definition `[^<\r\n]`. However, this is not a general solution!

Answer (score 1):

Do not under any circumstances try to parse HTML with a regex unless you wish to invoke [rite <sub>6</sub>6<sup>6</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) *Ph'nglui mglw'nafh Cthulhu R'lyeh wgah'nagl fhtagn.*

Use an HTML parsing library see [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114282/how-can-you-parse-html-in-android) for some ways to do it.